# Exception when deploying .war file on tomcat9.0.2 LifecycleExecption: Failed to start component

Tags: maven, tomcat, jsf

I am working on a web application at the moment. Now i was trying to deploy it as a .war file on my tomcat9.0.2 server.

Server:
centos 6.9 x32
java 1.8.0_152

My PC:
debian 9 x64
java 9

Exception

```
23-Dec-2017 14:55:48.217 INFORMATION [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 28153 ms
23-Dec-2017 15:02:58.348 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/NAVS]
23-Dec-2017 15:02:58.467 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.2/webapps/NAVS.war]
23-Dec-2017 15:02:59.248 INFORMATION [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers Unable to process ServletContainerInitializer for [com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer]. This is most likely due to a class defined in the @HandlesTypes annotation being missing. Enable DEBUG level logging for the full stack trace.
23-Dec-2017 15:03:03.377 SCHWERWIEGEND [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NAVS]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1847)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1619)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1366)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.cleanupInitMaps(InitFacesContext.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.<init>(InitFacesContext.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer.onStartup(FacesInitializer.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5094)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 19 more

23-Dec-2017 15:03:03.391 SCHWERWIEGEND [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.2/webapps/NAVS.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NAVS]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1847)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1619)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1366)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I would be very thankful, if someone could help me finding out what's wrong.

Comment: what jsf version are you using  .You have tried with last one ?

Comment: i'm using version 2.2

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem

Comment: you re welcome.